# Use Base Class on Doctrine 2 Entities?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am new to Doctrine (and ORM in general).  I have generated some entities modeled after my database, and it works great.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to extend the entity classes with a base class that has shared functionality.  For example, I could put magic methods for getters and setters in the base class.  Is this possible with Doctrine 2?

For example:

```
/**
 * Country
 *
 * @Table(name="country", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="country_id", columns={"country_id"})})
 * @Entity
 */
class Country extends MyBaseClass
{   
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Column(name="code", type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=75, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;
}

class MyBaseClass {
    public function doSomething($var) {
        return $this->$var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure.  Doctrine 2 entities are just plain old php objects.  Extend away.  Though I wold be a little bit careful about using __get as it might break lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity is general class, so you can easily extend some base class.
You can see examples of how to use this approach in [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) for example. Base classes and interfaces are placed under [model](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Model) folder.

Another way to share functionality are [traits](http://php.net/traits). You can have look on some general Doctrine 2 behaviors from KnpLabs [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors).